# ImageIO hangs when referred inside an OSGI Application Mac OS X - Java 1.7

Tags: java, osgi, osx-lion, javax.imageio, equinox

I am using Java 1.7 on Mac OS X 10.7.5 . It hangs the moment execution touches any ImageIO API.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplication;
import org.eclipse.equinox.app.IApplicationContext;

public class ImageMain implements IApplication {

    @Override
    public Object start(IApplicationContext context) throws Exception {

        ImageIO.getCacheDirectory();

         return IApplication.EXIT_OK; 
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

**jstack output :**

> 013-12-03 11:37:57
>       Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode):
>
> ```
> "Attach Listener" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbada8c5000 nid=0x8a23 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "Worker-JM" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb941000 nid=0x6007 in Object.wait() [0x0000000116ee6000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
>   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>   - waiting on <0x00000007f85bf428> (a java.util.ArrayList)
>   at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.InternalWorker.run(InternalWorker.java:58)
>   - locked <0x00000007f85bf428> (a java.util.ArrayList)
>
> "Start Level Event Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb92c800 nid=0x5d03 in Object.wait()
> ```
>
> [0x0000000115bbf000]
>          java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
>         at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>         - waiting on <0x00000007f96b2838> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
>         at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
>         - locked <0x00000007f96b2838> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
>         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)
>
> ```
> "State Saver" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb895800 nid=0x5b03 in Object.wait() [0x0000000115ab7000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>   at sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:271)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:260)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext.initMainAppContext(AppContext.java:260)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext.access$200(AppContext.java:133)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:314)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:298)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext(AppContext.java:297)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext$6.getContext(AppContext.java:841)
>   at sun.misc.SharedSecrets.getJavaAWTAccess(SharedSecrets.java:200)
>   at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultInAppContext(TimeZone.java:730)
>   at java.util.TimeZone.getDefaultRef(TimeZone.java:620)
>   at java.util.Date.normalize(Date.java:1193)
>   at java.util.Date.toString(Date.java:1027)
>   at java.util.Properties.store0(Properties.java:823)
>   at java.util.Properties.store(Properties.java:812)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.save(StorageManager.java:551)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.update(StorageManager.java:310)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.closeOutputStream(StorageManager.java:903)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.ManagedOutputStream.close(ManagedOutputStream.java:52)
>   at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:160)
>   at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(FilterOutputStream.java:160)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.saveBundleDatas(BaseStorage.java:598)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.saveAllData(BaseStorage.java:461)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage$StateSaver.run(BaseStorage.java:1306)
>   - locked <0x00000007f96b8c48> (a org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.SystemState)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>
> "Framework Event Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb948000 nid=0x5903 in Object.wait() [0x00000001159b6000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
>   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>   - waiting on <0x00000007f96b2520> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
>   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.getNextEvent(EventManager.java:400)
>   - locked <0x00000007f96b2520> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:336)
>
> "State Data Manager" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb828000 nid=0x5703 waiting for monitor entry [0x00000001158b3000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.StateManager.run(StateManager.java:303)
>   - waiting to lock <0x00000007f96b8c48> (a org.eclipse.osgi.internal.resolver.SystemState)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>
> "Framework Active Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb05b800 nid=0x5503 in Object.wait() [0x00000001157b0000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
>   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>   - waiting on <0x00000007f96b7310> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework)
>   at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.run(Framework.java:1862)
>   - locked <0x00000007f96b7310> (a org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
>
> "Service Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad9806000 nid=0x4f03 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadc001800 nid=0x4d03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb829800 nid=0x4b03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "JDWP Command Reader" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadd002000 nid=0x4903 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "JDWP Event Helper Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadd000000 nid=0x4703 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "JDWP Transport Listener: dt_socket" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb828800 nid=0x4503 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb81a000 nid=0x4303 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>
> "Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb803000 nid=0x3a03 in Object.wait() [0x0000000114b56000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
>   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>   - waiting on <0x00000007f96e30b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
>   - locked <0x00000007f96e30b0> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
>   at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
>   at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:189)
>
> "Reference Handler" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007fbadb800800 nid=0x3803 in Object.wait() [0x0000000114a53000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
>   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
>   - waiting on <0x00000007f96e2af8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
>   at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
>   at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
>   - locked <0x00000007f96e2af8> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
>
> "main" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad9041000 nid=0x707 runnable [0x00007fff6ccd1000]
>    java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
>   - locked <0x00000007f96e20e0> (a java.util.Vector)
>   - locked <0x00000007f96a0ad8> (a java.util.Vector)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1843)
>   at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:795)
>   - locked <0x00000007f9727830> (a java.lang.Runtime)
>   at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1061)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1957)
>   - locked <0x00000007f96e20e0> (a java.util.Vector)
>   - locked <0x00000007f96a0ad8> (a java.util.Vector)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1882)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1864)
>   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
>   - locked <0x00000007f9727830> (a java.lang.Runtime)
>   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1087)
>   at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:67)
>   at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:47)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1646)
>   at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1668)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:271)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext$2.run(AppContext.java:260)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext.initMainAppContext(AppContext.java:260)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext.access$200(AppContext.java:133)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:314)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext$3.run(AppContext.java:298)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at sun.awt.AppContext.getAppContext(AppContext.java:297)
>   at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(IIORegistry.java:154)
>   at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(ImageIO.java:65)
>   at com.sap.ImageTest.ImageMain.start(ImageMain.java:13)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
>   at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
>   at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
>
> "VM Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad908e000 nid=0x3603 runnable 
>
> "GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad904d000 nid=0x2603 runnable 
>
> "GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad904d800 nid=0x2803 runnable 
>
> "GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad904e000 nid=0x2a03 runnable 
>
> "GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad904e800 nid=0x2c03 runnable 
>
> "GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad904f800 nid=0x2e03 runnable 
>
> "GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad9050000 nid=0x3003 runnable 
>
> "GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad9050800 nid=0x3203 runnable 
>
> "GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbad9051000 nid=0x3403 runnable 
>
> "VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007fbada801000 nid=0x5103 waiting on condition 
>
> JNI global references: 2810
> ```

Comment: 1) *"Thanks,
Dav"*  Noise.  Leave it out in future.  2) *"what could be the reason?"*  Corrupted image?  Bug in the JRE?  Can you upload the image to a file share site so we can see it?

Comment: Can you do a stack dump of the running process (the thread that does the reading only, please), and update your question? Use `jstack` on the command line. And link to an image, as already suggested.

Comment: It seems from the stack trace and some googling, that the problem is initialization of the AWT from within an OSGI module. But even if you do initialize AWT properly, there may be (class loader related) issues with ImageIO's service registry as it isn't designed for use with OSGI. Someone with more OSGI experience might give better answers though... :-)

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395318

Answer (score 5):

indeed Oracle has an issue on this but not related to ISGI but to the Mac JRE: http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8019496
You may try to add this to you launch configuration.
-Djava.awt.headless=true

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug only on Mac OS X.
I had the same problem on a Mac and switching to a PC (Java 1.7) solved the problem.

In my code I am using

```
File file = new File( "my/path" );
ImageIO.read( file ); // <-- Hangs here
System.out.println( "Never logged" );
```