# Does JAI work inside an OSGI on MAC OS >10.7 + Java 1.7?

Tags: osgi, equinox, jai

I am trying to use JAI (JAVA Advanced Imaging) API inside an OSGI Application on MAC . But it doesnt seem to load JAI and hence gets hung . Have someone succeeded in using javax.media inside osgi on mac ?

Ex: Trying somthing like this ...

```
RenderedImage image = JAI.create("fileload", "tuc.jpg");
```

Thanks,
Dav

Comment: Please provide the error message (if any) and a more detailed description of what happens when you run the above code.

Comment: I guess it does not hurt to try.. But, as JAI uses a lot of the same classes as ImageIO and internally uses a lot of the same mechanisms, you are likely to run into the [same issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330807/imageio-hangs-when-referred-inside-an-osgi-application-mac-os-x-java-1-7) here. I suggest googling more and ask in different forums (eg. Eclipse/Equinox list), if you don't get the answers you want on SO.

Comment: Given the stack traces in your other post, I would suggest some experimenting to see where the issue is. Like: use a different platform, different VM, write a simple bundle which does the same thing but outside eclipse, etc. It wouldn't surprise me that this is the result of a very specific combination of platform/VM/Eclipse.